# Ruby add value to json array

Tags: json, ruby

I have this json code:

```
{
  "kind": "something",
  "rules": [
    {
      "rule1": [
        "something1",
        "something2",
        "something3"
      ],
      "rule2": "something"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to add something4 to rule1. How can I do this in Ruby?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let `json_string` be your JSON string

```
require 'json'

h = JSON.parse(json_string)
h["rules"][0]["rule1"] << "something4"
```

Comment: Can you do `h[:rules][0][:rule1] << 'something4'` without requiring the `json` gem?

Answer (score 0):

### Your Nesting Structure Uses Keys *and* Indexes

Your problem is that your JSON is really poorly-designed for finding specific keys, because the various rules are actually wrapped inside an array. In your example, you only have one, but if you have more array elements then you've got to find the *right* array element to modify. It can be done with a lot of work via [Enumerable#each_with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) or a related method, but if you are confident of the structure of your JSON you can take a shortcut.

```
require 'json'

json = <<~'EOF'
  {
    "kind": "something",
    "rules": [
      {
        "rule1": [
          "something1",
          "something2",
          "something3"
        ],
        "rule2": "something"
      }
    ]
  }
EOF

# Get the first array from "rules", and append the string
# to the array inside the hash value referenced by the
# "rule1" key.
hash['rules'].first['rule1'] << 'something4'

puts JSON.pretty_generate(hash)
```

> ```
> {
>  "kind": "something",
>  "rules": [
>    {
>      "rule1": [
>        "something1",
>        "something2",
>        "something3",
>        "something4"
>      ],
>      "rule2": "something"
>    }
>  ]
> }
> ```

In the real world, you'd likely have to iterate over the *rules* array to find the index of the array element you want to modify. After that, you can find the *rule1* key and append the value you want to the value's hash.

Answer (score 0):

Saying that you assign that code to a variable

```
settings = {
  "kind": "something",
  "rules": [
    {
      "rule1": [
        "something1",
        "something2",
        "something3"
      ],
      "rule2": "something"
    }
  ]
}
```

you can do this:

```
settings["rules"][0]["rule1"] << "test"
```